# REST AJAX cross-domain not executing callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, callback, cross-domain

I'm having a lot of trouble to execute cross domain REST call with Jquery ajax function.

Here is code:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: restUrl,
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain : true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: false,
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallbackTest',
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log('not OK '+xhr);
                    console.log('not OK '+status);
                    console.log('not OK '+error);
                },
                success: function(jsonp) {
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
```

and this is what I get in Firebug console:

not OK [object Object] Init.js:872
not OK parsererror Init.js:873
not OK Error: jsonpCallbackTest was not called

What am I doing wrong?

regards Matej

Comment: where is this function `jsonpCallbackTest`?

Comment: outside function with ajax call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

It's difficult to say from the code information you provided in your question. There could be many reasons. For example the remote REST webservice that you are trying to invoke returns a JSON response instead of JSONP.

Also you seem to have defined the `jsonpCallbackTest` function and yet you are using an anonymous success handler which are incompatible. Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: restUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallbackTest',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('not OK '+xhr);
        console.log('not OK '+status);
        console.log('not OK '+error);
    }
});
```

and then define the jsonpCallbackTest function:

```
function jsonpCallbackTest(jsonp) {
    alert("success");
}
```

You will also have to check the documentation of the remote web service how to specify the JSONP callback. Whether you could pass it as query string parameter.

It's usually preferred to leave jQuery pass a random callback function name to the web service:

```
$.ajax({
    url: restUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('not OK '+xhr);
        console.log('not OK '+status);
        console.log('not OK '+error);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, for your answer but if I try your code I get:              not OK [object Object] 
not OK parsererror 
not OK Error: jQuery1720902001413051039_1341388798594 was not called I changed my parameter from jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallbackTest', to jsonpCallback: jsonpCallbackTest, and now this function is executed, but I cannot get parameters from ajax call to this function. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Missed a comma ',' for success function

Comment: @Sobis, the `jsonpCallback` parameter is a string. You should **not** change it to `jsonpCallback: jsonpCallbackTest`, this is wrong. Did you try my last code sample? Did you check the documentation of the RESTful web service you are trying to invoke what is the parameter name that you need to pass for the callback? Which url are you trying to invoke? Is it publicly accessible? I may help you if you provide more details.

Comment: Yes I tried your code, but it doesn't work. If I try your first ajax call I get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.100.106:2080/ResEvo.Mind.Rest/rest/admin/workspace/postgres. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." and if I try your second code I get " Error: jQuery17206285656029358506_1341389497129 was not called " error

Comment: When you navigate directly to the `http://192.168.100.106:2080/ResEvo.Mind.Rest/rest/admin/workspace/postgres` address in your browser what do you see? JSON or JSONP response?

Comment: I get [{"name":"Demo","description":""}] for resposne

Comment: Well, that's JSON, not JSONP. I don't know how can you even expect that to work. In order to perform cross domain AJAX calls your service needs to support JSONP. The correct answer must have been `someCallbackName([{"name":"Demo","description":""}])`. That's why I asked you many times the following question and you never answered me. So let me repeat it once again: does your service support JSONP? If, yes what query string parameter name does it expect in order to define the callback name?

Comment: Do I need to support that on server side? That will be very hard to do. Is there any way to support that on client side?

Comment: For example what happens if you try the following url: `http://192.168.100.106:2080/ResEvo.Mind.Rest/rest/admin/workspace/postgres?callback=abc`? Do you still get JSON?

Comment: JSONP must be supported on the server. If it is not you can forget about cross domain AJAX. If you don't have control over the remote service you will have to write a proxy service on your own domain that will delegate the call to the remote service. Then send the AJAX request to your own service.

Comment: But maybe the parameter name is different? Not `callback`. Check the documentation if this service supports JSONP. If it doesn't you really can't do much from the client side. For security reasons there are same origin policy restrictions built into web browsers which prevent you from sending cross domain AJAX calls.

Comment: I'll try to change server side or I'll create proxy server for this call. Thaks for your answers, it really helped me a lot.

Comment: Sobis I've the same problem. 
The error message is 

Console Error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"
STATUS: parseerror, 
ERROR: jQuery1110072177085862495_1399027696440 was not called

My ajax call is:
$.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "http://54.225.213.167/developer-assessment/api",
        dataType:"jsonp",
        type: "GET"

    }).done(function(data, status, xhr){
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    });

even if the result calling the url directly is a JSON obj.